# Spring Boot AngularJs Application: Shows reference error for Angular

Tags: angularjs, wro4j

I am following below tutorial [Spring and Angular JS: A Secure Single Page Application](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application)

The pom.xml is below -

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>single</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>single</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>${angularjs.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine</artifactId>
            <version>${jasmine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <angularjs.version>1.4.9</angularjs.version>
        <bootstrap.version>3.3.7-1</bootstrap.version>
        <jquery.version>2.2.4</jquery.version>
        <jasmine.version>2.0.0</jasmine.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute
                          path for the project -->
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${project.build.directory}/wro</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                        <version>${jquery.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                        <version>${angularjs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**wro.xml :**

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
  <group name="angular-bootstrap">
    <css>webjar:bootstrap/@bootstrap.version@/less/bootstrap.less</css>
    <css>file:@project.basedir@/src/main/wro/main.less</css>
    <js>webjar:jquery/@jquery.version@/jquery.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular-route.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/@angularjs.version@/angular-cookies.min.js</js>
   </group>
</groups>
```

**Index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<link
    href="css/angular-bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="rolb" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/hello.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navigationController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/subscriptionController.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js :**

```
angular.module('rolb', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeController'       
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigationController'     
    }).when('/subscribeConfirm', {
        templateUrl : 'subscribe.html',
        controller : 'subscriptionController'       
    }).otherwise('/');

   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
   /*if this is not set , after successfull authentication for first time , the next request doesn't contain JSESSIONID and hence session is not established 
   requiring again /login request*/
   $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

})
```

**HomeController.js :**

```
angular.module('rolb').controller('homeController',[$http,$scope,$rootScope,$location,function($http,$scope,$rootScope,$location) {
    var self = this;
    /*$http.get('/resource/').then(function(response) {
        self.greeting = response.data;
    })*/

    $scope.subscribe = function(prodId) {

        var url = "http://localhost:8080/springbootrest/productSubscription/"+prodId+"/"+$scope.selectedAccount;
        $http.post(url).success(function(data) {                        
            $location.path("/subscribeConfirm");
        }).error(function(data) {
            $scope.error = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = data.message;
        })                      
    }

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/springbootrest/products').success(function(data) {                     
        if (data) {                 
            $scope.products = data;
        } else {

        }           
    }).error(function(data) {

    })  

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/springbootrest/accounts').success(function(data) {                     
        if (data) {                 
            $scope.accounts = data;
        } else {

        }           
    }).error(function(data) {

    })  

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/springbootrest/subscribedProducts').success(function(data) {                       
        if (data) {                 
            $scope.subscribedProducts = data;
        } else {

        }           
    }).error(function(data) {

    })      


}])
```

**Home.html  :**

```
<h1>Welcome To ANB Online Banking </h1>
<div ng-show="authenticated">

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show=loginError>
        There was a problem logging in. Please try again.
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show=error>
        {{errorMessage}}
    </div>

    <p>Welcome User {{userName}}  to Online Banking </p>

    We have following products available for you 
    <br/>
    <br/>

     <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Product Description</th>
                <th>Minimum Balance</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="prod in products">
                <td>{{prod.productName}}</td>
                <td>{{prod.description}}</td>
                <td>{{prod.minBalance}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="subscribe(prod.productId)">Subscribe</button></td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
     </table>

     <br/>
     <br/>

    You have following accounts linked . Please select an account to debit money from :
    <select ng-model="selectedAccount" ng-options="acnt.accountId as acnt.accountType for acnt in accounts">        
    </select>

     <br/>
     <br/>

    <div ng-show="subscribedProducts.length > 0 ">

        Your have subscribed to following products currently. 
         <br/>

        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Product Description</th>
                    <th>Minimum Balance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="subscribedProds in subscribedProducts">
                    <td>{{subscribedProds.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{subscribedProds.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{subscribedProds.minBalance}}</td>         
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
         </table>               
    </div>


</div>
<div ng-show="!authenticated">
    <p>Login</p>
</div>
```

When I access index.html , I am getting below error. 
ReferenceError: $http is not defined

I have verified in browser that the angular-botstrap.js getting loaded successfully. 
[image]
All Angular controllers are loaded AFTER angular-bootstrap.js , still I am getting this error.

Can anybody please help here , as I am not getting any clue why is this happening ?

Comment: What does it say in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are missing the reference for **`angular.js`** and **`angular-route.js`** which are needed since you are injecting ngRoute as a dependency, also change your script reference order as follows.

```
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navigationController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/subscriptionController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . But If you can see in updated question , I am using wro.xml to group all angular dependencies in one file. (angular-bootstrap.js) , as per the tutorial. wro.xml specifies angular.js and angular-route.js as specified in xml.  So does this mean that these two files are not getting packed in angular-bootstrap.js giving reference error ?

Comment: @Atul check if they have been loaded in netwrok tab/console

Comment: Yes , they are . As per screen shot shown in question.That is why I am not able to understand why reference error is coming

Comment: i dont see them in the screenshot

Comment: They should be loaded as part of angular.bootsrap.js .

Comment: i guess thats where the problem lies

Comment: Yes . Thanks . Referencing angular.js and angular-route.js in index.html gives 404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161921/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-atul).